# ASP.net MVC: Creating a Simple Log-in Form in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm creating a simple ASP.net MVC login form using individual user accounts. I created the project following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

At what point do I connect it to my SQL Server database? In the tutorial, it seems as though the database tables are created automatically, though I've never seen an option to enter my database credentials.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default template generates you a local database that is stored in the project directory. If I recall correctly, it does not require authentication. You can examine the Web.config file to see the connection string. It will not contain a username and password because it does not require them for that local database.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the .mdf and .ldf files associated with this project, as well as the connection string. Is there an easy way to migrate those local DB files to SQL server?

Comment: Thank you - I've figured it out!